# macro alert- value crossing a specific Number

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table, where the cell data is streamed from outside (like stock-market), my table looks like this: 
1. Table has some 250 rows;
2. 1st column (A) has the name and Column B has the rating

During any point if the rating is crossing 3, than I would like to get a pop-up alert window were the message sould be like "Name:XXXXX just crossed rating: 3"

XXXXX is the corresponding cell value in the table of Column A, where the rating is just changed

Thank you
Jay

Comment: "Crossing 3" meaning greater than 3?

Comment: Are you wanting this to be real time (notify when it changes) or executed on a command?

Comment: @urdearboy - yes the values change rapidly and it needs to be a real-time

Comment: If the rating is calculated from an equation, a worksheet_change event won’t directly work. You need to determine what changes MAY trigger a change in your equation and launch a event check then. Currently not enough info to provide solution to your problem

Comment: @urdearboy ok... in any way can I talk to you? so that I can brief my challange

Comment: Update your question to show how the rating is being calculated - the equation will update itself when certain cells change. To complete your ask, we need to know what cells are physically being changed (rather cells that are changing from an equation update)

Comment: The various columns are: A) Name ; B) Rating; C) Total no of requests processed ; D) total hours spent so my rating is calculated as  B = [(C*D)/count of Names]

Answer (score 0):

```
for each row in ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    if Cells(Row.Row,"B")>3 then 
        MsgBox Cells(Row.Row,"A").value & " has just crossed rating: 3"
    end if
next row
```

Comment: I don't know how wise it is to loop through every single row.  More realistically, you could find the last row in column B, then work to that row instead.  Will save you checking potentially 1,048,576 rows when you only needed 3.

Comment: Also, it sounds like OP wants this to be automatic (real time). This code has to be manually executed.

Comment: @BruceWayne That's a good point. Will edit my answer to use .UsedRange

Comment: The above code doesn't give me the corresponding name value when the rating is changed over 3

Comment: Hi All, need to have this macro running in the background, instend of running everytime manual and when ever the value in 'Rating' changes, I must get the alert as its not possible to keep looking at the excel sheet all the time